# Return values from a MySQL database that match a specific PHP variable?

Tags: php, mysql, select, where-clause

I'm building a simple to-do site just to help me learn mySQL a bit better.  I'm having a bit of trouble getting the values to return.  When i use "SELECT * FROM pages" as my query, all the data comes back fine. (pages is the table name)

However, what I want to do is only pull back a row of data for one particular user.  In order to do this, I'm using a unique URL field in the database (previously created with another function) to select which row to return data for.

I'm missing something simple here that I was hoping someone could spot for me.  With the following code, I get a series of this error that corresponds to the 7 variables I'm trying to output: (i'm aware of SQL injection issues, this is only for simplicity's sake.  Also, please forgive the over-commenting, I'm learning, and that's the only way I can keep up with my work)

Warning: mysql_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /test/preview.php on line 16

```
<?php
include './includes/dbcon.php';

//declare $preview_url as the data submitted in the form under the 'preview_url' field
$preview_url = ($_POST['preview_url']);

//access db settings included in ./includes/dbcon.php
mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

//select the row in the table that matches the passed variable from the form submission
$query="SELECT * FROM 'pages' WHERE 'url' = '".$preview_url."'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

// assign mySQL values from table to php variables
$email = mysql_result($result,1,'email');
$date=mysql_result($result,1,"date");
$title=mysql_result($result,1,"title");
$id=mysql_result($result,1,"id");
$items=mysql_result($result,1,"items");
$url=mysql_result($result,1,"url");
$expiry=mysql_result($result,1,"expiry");

//close the mySQL connection        
mysql_close();

?>

<html>
<head><title>Preview for <? echo $email; ?></title></head>
<body>
<strong>Email: </strong><a href="mailto:<? echo $email; ?>"><? echo $email; ?></a>        
<br />
<strong>Title: </strong><? echo $title; ?><br />
<strong>Date: </strong><? echo $date; ?><br />
<strong>Entry ID: </strong><? echo $id; ?><br />
<strong>Unique URL: </strong><a href="<? echo $url; ?>" target="_blank"><? echo          
$url; ?></a><br />
<strong>Link Expiration Date: </strong><? echo $expiry; ?><br />
<hr />
<strong>List:</strong><br />
<? echo $items; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First get rid of the quotes around `'pages'` and use backticks. That alone will break your query. Plus the quotes around `WHERE 'url'` which is most likely the cause.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d. You are also using an obsolete and deprecated mysql interface library. Stop working on this code until you've learned about injection attack defense and switched to a supported library, e.g. mysqli (note the `i`) or PDO.

Comment: @MarcB Really? That would require someone giving a crap who/what he is. Seriously, the SQL injection thing is real, serious, should be addressed, but not trolled. *sigh*

Comment: @MarcB Didn't read the entire question, eh? And I quote: *i'm aware of SQL injection issues, this is only for simplicity's sake.*

Comment: @Edwin, You are not checking if the $result value from mysql_query is valid before giving it to mysql_result. This is called error checking. Fix the syntax error -> FROM 'pages' to FROM `pages` <-- backtick not apostrophe for field/table names. Then do if (!$result) { die(mysql_error()); } before calling mysql_result....

Comment: Anybody who's hungry for points, can go right ahead; be my guest. [I've said what needed to be done](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910762/return-values-from-a-mysql-database-that-match-a-specific-php-variable#comment31390888_20910762) to (most likely) fix this puppy. I don't want to fall into a "can of worms"; it's creepy down there.

Comment: If you really want to learn mysql you should skip the deprecated `mysql_*` functions and go straight to PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this code portion Edwin

```
//select the row in the table that matches the passed variable from the form submission
$query="SELECT * FROM `pages` WHERE `url` = '".$preview_url."'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_error());
}

// assign mySQL values from table to php variables
$email = mysql_result($result,1,'email');
$date=mysql_result($result,1,"date");
$title=mysql_result($result,1,"title");
$id=mysql_result($result,1,"id");
$items=mysql_result($result,1,"items");
$url=mysql_result($result,1,"url");
$expiry=mysql_result($result,1,"expiry");

//close the mySQL connection        
mysql_close();
```

Also, if you are truly hungry to be learning, then know that mysql_ functions are deprecated and will dissapear soon. Learn to use the mysqli_ functionality and PDO.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php

Comment: Let's just hope now that the OP doesn't invite you to supper for "worms" à la mode! ;-)

Comment: Afraid I don't catch the reference Fred

Comment: Well, questions like these tend to go South, as it were.

Comment: By "a can of worms" I mean, that it happens that more bugs come out of these types of questions.

Comment: Only because of trolls. I'm glad my teachers didn't trash me when I did something that wasn't up to par. My teacher said, 'This is the better way'.

Comment: `WHERE 'url' = '".$preview_url."'` is still wrong. Because it will only match if `$preview_url == 'url'`...

Comment: LOL! Exactly @Rottingham Do the job right, instead of doing it thrice later on.

Comment: Apart from the quotes, you should also add protection against sql injection.

Comment: Thanks all for the quick response.  I changed the " to ` in the query, and added error correction.  It is working properly now.  I appreciate the help tremendously, even the browbeating for the SQL injection vulnerabilities. :)

Comment: Good job Edwin. Do take it seriously, as it can cause drastic affects to you and clients down the road.  Also, make sure you leave mysql_. Its deprecated, you might as well learn the right stuff.

Comment: Glad we could help @EdwinJ P.s.: Do read the comments. They can hold many [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910762/return-values-from-a-mysql-database-that-match-a-specific-php-variable#comment31390888_20910762) as well. ;-) when there's a `1` (or more) next to them, it means that someone agreed.

Comment: `Another Happy Ending`